# Google Maps marker won't display

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am working on a project where I need to display bike stations in a given city, retrieving data from an API and also using Google Maps API. I followed everything on Google documentation but can't seem to display the markers.

I tried passing a bike station position parameters directly in the google.maps.Marker but it won't display either.

JavaScript:

```
class GoogleMap {
    constructor(latGmap, lngGmap, zoomGmap) {
        this.latGmap = latGmap
        this.lngGmap = lngGmap
        this.zoomGmap = zoomGmap
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: { lat: this.latGmap, lng: this.lngGmap },
            zoom: this.zoomGmap
        })
    }
}

class Station {
    constructor(stationName, stationStatus, stationAddress, stationAvailableBikes, stationAvailableBikeStands, stationLat, stationLng) {
        this.stationName = stationName;
        this.stationStatus = stationStatus;
        this.stationAddress = stationAddress;
        this.stationAvailableBikes = stationAvailableBikes;
        this.stationAvailableBikeStands = stationAvailableBikeStands;
        this.stationLat = stationLat;
        this.stationLng = stationLng;
    }
}

const fetchData = async function () {
    let dataURL = "https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=amiens&apiKey=4cb8707fc70c97865d22d1324513f8e6464ed37b";

    try {
        let response = await fetch(dataURL)
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        }
        else {
            console.error('Retour du serveur : ', response.status)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

let map;

function initMap() {
    let googleMap = new GoogleMap(49.893034, 2.297347, 14);

    fetchData().then(data => {

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let station = data[i]
            let stations = new Station(station.name, station.status, station.address, station.available_bikes, station.available_bike_stands, station.position.lat, station.position.lng)

            let lat = stations.stationLat;
            let lng = stations.stationLng;

            let location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
            let labels = station.available_bikes.toString();

            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                label: labels,
                map: map
            })
            console.log(marker)
        }
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAeMga8sAPw4m43CMWgFu_SNunKJxjyoLg&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

With the fetched data I should get 26 markers displayed but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` variable is not defined where you are creating the markers (so they aren't added to the map).

```
function initMap() {
  let googleMap = new GoogleMap(49.893034, 2.297347, 14);
  var map = googleMap.map;  // or just use googleMap.map where map is being used
  // ...
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dLz1myuf/6/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
class GoogleMap {
  constructor(latGmap, lngGmap, zoomGmap) {
    this.latGmap = latGmap
    this.lngGmap = lngGmap
    this.zoomGmap = zoomGmap
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: {
        lat: this.latGmap,
        lng: this.lngGmap
      },
      zoom: this.zoomGmap
    })
  }
}

class Station {
  constructor(stationName, stationStatus, stationAddress, stationAvailableBikes, stationAvailableBikeStands, stationLat, stationLng) {
    this.stationName = stationName;
    this.stationStatus = stationStatus;
    this.stationAddress = stationAddress;
    this.stationAvailableBikes = stationAvailableBikes;
    this.stationAvailableBikeStands = stationAvailableBikeStands;
    this.stationLat = stationLat;
    this.stationLng = stationLng;
  }
}

const fetchData = async function() {
  let dataURL = "https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=amiens&apiKey=4cb8707fc70c97865d22d1324513f8e6464ed37b";

  try {
    let response = await fetch(dataURL)
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()
    } else {
      console.error('Retour du serveur : ', response.status)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

let map;

function initMap() {
  let googleMap = new GoogleMap(49.893034, 2.297347, 14);
  var map = googleMap.map;
  fetchData().then(data => {

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let station = data[i]
      let stations = new Station(station.name, station.status, station.address, station.available_bikes, station.available_bike_stands, station.position.lat, station.position.lng)

      let lat = stations.stationLat;
      let lng = stations.stationLng;

      let location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
      let labels = station.available_bikes.toString();

      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        label: labels,
        map: map
      })
      console.log(marker)
    }
  })
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar class I have, you are welcome to adapt

```
/**
 *    'GMap'
 *    extends googlemaps to allow simpler coding in other apps, should be loaded after the main google maps
 *    a new instance of a google map is contructed calling this with identical arguments to the standard class and then returned
 *    the map name must be unique and reserved as a global by the client code, eg var pagemap outside of function, so the external callbacks
 *    can use this name to run a function against, eg pagemap.queryMove_do
 *
 */
class GMap {
    constructor(parentElem, args) {
        this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        this.markers = {};
        this.markerbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var args = model.array_defaults(args,
            {
                instanceName: "gMap",
                mapID: "mapFrame",
                address: null,//address will override center
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.509865, -0.118092),
                zoom: 9,
                minzoom: 15,
                maxzoom: 21
            })
        this.name = args.instanceName;
        $("#" + parentElem).prepend("<div id='" + args.mapID + "' class='mapframe'></div>");
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(args.mapID), args);
        if (args.address) {
            this.panToAddress(args.address);
        }
    }

    getAddressLocation(id, query, callback) {
        this.geocoder.geocode({"address": query}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == "OK") {
                location = {lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()};
            }
            else {
                var location = null;
            }
            eval(callback + "(" + id + ",status,location)");
        });
    }

    setMarker(title, location, optargs) {
        optargs=model.array_defaults(optargs,{
            infowindow:false,
            label:{},
            zIndex: 0,
            icon: "/DD_libmedia/images/icons/white-red-dot.png"//source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Red_circle_(thin).svg
        });
        if (optargs.infowindow) {
            var infocontent = "<div id='" + optargs.infowindow.id + "' class='infowindowFrame'><h5>" + optargs.infowindow.title + "</h5>" + optargs.infowindow.content + "<br />";
            for (var b in optargs.infowindow.buttons) {
                var button= view.getBtnCFG(
                    optargs.infowindow.buttons[b]
                );
                infocontent +=button.dhtml;
            }
            infocontent += "</div>";
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: infocontent
            });
        }
        var markericon = {
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
            url: optargs.icon
        };

        var markerposition = {lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng};

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            title: title,
            label:optargs.label,
            position: markerposition,
            map: ctrl.map.map,
            icon: markericon,
            zIndex: optargs.zIndex,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

        this.markerbounds.extend(markerposition);

        if (optargs.infowindow) {
            marker.addListener('click', function () {
                infowindow.open(ctrl.map.map, marker);
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * zoomToMarkers
     * where markers have been set with this.setMarker then zoomToMarkers will zoom the map to the marker boundaries
     * see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees
     *
     * LAT
     * + is north of the equator, - is south of the equator
     *
     * LNG
     * + is east of Greenwich
     * - is west of Greenwich
     *
     * Latitude and longitude are usually expressed in that sequence, latitude before longitude.
     */
    zoomToMarkers() {
        this.map.fitBounds(this.markerbounds, {bottom: 2, left: 2, right: 2, top: 2});
    }

    panTo(latLng,zoomlevel){
        this.map.panTo(latLng);
        this.map.setZoom(zoomlevel);
    }

    panToAddress(address) {
        this.geocoder.geocode({"address": address}, function (results, status) {
            //xonservice.gotLocation(results, status);
        });
    }


}
```